# PowerShell - Copy one Computer text file to another computer

Tags: powershell, remote-server, file-copying

On the same domain [domain.net] I have two computers.
The first computer has a test malware text file that is saved in a location that is invisible to my antivirus Symantec [due to permissions and so forth].

What I want to do is copy the file from the first computer [which is the computer I am currently logged into when running the program] and copy the file to the other computer that I am not logged into. [**purpose down the road is to test the antivirus protection monitoring on 100+ PCs**]

When I try the following code I get the error:

```
[pc#] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot complete the operation within the time specified. Check if the machine name is valid and is reachable over the network and firewall exception for Windows Remote Management service is enabled. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

For my code below:

```
$Username = "domain.net\usernameID"
$Password = get-content "C:\Users\usernameID\Documents\passwordhash.txt" | convertto-securestring

$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password

Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC# -Credential $mySecureCreds -ScriptBlock {
Copy-Item -Path "C:\ProgramData\MalFolder\MalwareTest.txt" -Destination "\\domain.net\c$\Desktop\" -Recurse
}
```

**Is there anyway to bypass this issue without having to change the firewall to allow Remoting [overall don't want this for security purposes] ?**

**Or is the way I am doing this incorrect?**

```
*******************************************************************
```

**I have also tried:**

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC# -Credential $mySecureCreds -ScriptBlock {
Copy-Item -Path "C:\ProgramData\MalFolder\MalwareTest.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\usernameID\Desktop\"
}
```

but get same error.

**Also tried:**

```
$computers = "PC#"
# This is the directory you want to copy to the computer (IE. c:\folder_to_be_copied) 
$source = "C:\ProgramData\MalFolder\MalwareTest.txt"
# On the desination computer, where do you want the folder to be copied? 
$dest = "c$" 
foreach ($computer in $computers) { 
if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) { 
    Copy-Item $source -Destination \\$computer\$dest -Recurse 
} else { 
    "$computer is not online" 
}
```

}

but get error:

```
Copy-Item : The specified network name is no longer available.
```

Reference: http://www.signalwarrant.com/2012/10/04/copy-a-folder-and-files-to-multiple-computers-powershell/

Comment: Is this a programming question or a malware cleanup/Windows security question?

Comment: programming question. I want to know how to get my text file copied to the other pc's desktop @Bill_Stewart

Comment: source `C:\ProgramData\MalFolder\MalwareTest.txt` is the first computer I am logged into and `"\\domain.net\c$\Desktop\"` is second computer @Bill_Stewart

Comment: You will need either File Sharing, or WinRM enabled to do it the ways you've presented.

Comment: As @Eris said, you have to have remote access to be able to copy to another computer. But that's not a programming a programming question; it's a "how does Windows network security work?" question.